# insert tag after content-children

Tags: plone, diazo

I'm trying to insert a custom tag into the page

should this work?

```
<after css:content-children="#viewlet-below-content-body">
   <a href="@@historyview">History</a>
</after>
```

seems only replace allows me to insert/replace a custom tag

```
<replace css:content-children="#viewlet-below-content-body">
   <a href="@@historyview">History</a>
</replace>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The before/after rules with only content/content-children is not supported by Diazo, you can only drop or replace. Maybe in a future version.

Answer (score 1):

How about appending your own tag to the theme (with also copying/replacing the children):

```
<append css:theme="#theme-id-for-viewlet-below-content-body">
   <a href="@@historyview">History</a>
</append>
```

Comment: i insert almost the whole #content, so i just misused/replaced one of the viewletslots